# How to append to file without repeating (for loops)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

So I want to append everything in the `links` array to a text file: `links.txt`. The problem is it appends everything times the number of iterations the loop goes through. I've tried putting the `fs.appendFileSync` outside but I need it to go after the request promise.

Here is the code:

```
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
var options = {
    uri: 'https://www.collegeconfidential.com/dean/page/' + i,
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};
rp(options).then(function($) {
    $('main#main > article.post').each(function() {
        // Fetches each question title, link, and adds a new line
        var maintxt = $(this).find('h3.entry-title > a');
        console.log("Question: " + maintxt.text().trim() + '\n' + "Link: " + maintxt.attr('href') + '\n\n');
        questions.push(maintxt.text().trim());
        links.push(maintxt.attr("href"));

    });
                // console.log(questions);
                // console.log(links);
}).then(function ($) {
    fs.appendFileSync('links.txt', links);
    console.log(links);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Crawling failed or Cheerio choked...
    console.log('Crawling failed or Cheerio choked')
});
}
```

Comment: For example, if the loop runs twice, then the fs.appendFileSync code will run twice. I will have two copies of the same code. How do I put the for loop inside a request and get the fs.appendFileSync to wait for the promise ?

Comment: What do you expect when writing an array to a file?

Comment: So, do you think only appending the last item of the array to the file will work?

Comment: If you really don't want everything times the number of iterations the loop goes through, couldn't you just clear out your links after each call to `fs.appendFileSync('links.txt', links);`?  Something like `while (links.length) { links.pop(); }` maybe?

Comment: Thanks Justin, that worked and made sense!

Answer (score 0):

Although this loop is not ideal...if you do not want to modify the array, you can just append the last added link in the array.

Replace:

```
fs.appendFileSync('links.txt', links);
```

With:

```
fs.appendFileSync('links.txt', links[links.length-1]+'\n');
```